# Problem in going froma fragment to activity through intent in android although intent for map works

Tags: android, android-intent, fragment

I have a fragment in which there are two buttons, one linking it to GoogleMap API which works perfectly fine whereas the other one linking to another activity crashes.

```
public class XBeeReceivedPacketsFragment extends AbstractXBeeDeviceFragment
{
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        // Inflate the layout for this fragment.
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.xbee_received_data, container, false);
        initializeUIElements(view);
        return view;
        }

private void initializeUIElements(View view) {
btn_Minedb=view.findViewById(R.id.btn_Minedb);
        btn_Minedb.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
                                      {
                                          @Override
                                          public void onClick(View v) {

                                              Intent intent=new Intent(XBeeReceivedPacketsFragment.this.getActivity(), MineDatabase.class);
                                              startActivity(intent);
                                          }


                                      }
        );


        btn_Map=view.findViewById(R.id.btn_Map);
        btn_Map.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
                                   {
                                       @Override
                                       public void onClick(View v) {

                                           Intent intent=new Intent(XBeeReceivedPacketsFragment.this.getActivity(), MapsActivity.class);
                                           startActivity(intent);
                                       }


                                   }
        );
}
```

and here is the code for the activity where the intent is directing,However the app carshes everytime I click this button

```
package com.digi.xbee.sample.android.xbeemanager.fragments;



import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.digi.xbee.sample.android.xbeemanager.R;


public class MineDatabase extends AppCompatActivity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mine_database);
     

    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: Unfortunately I can't debug using logcat since I need to attach some hardware to usb for running the app.I just want to know the basic programming flaw that I am making

Comment: can't help without a stacktrace unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

Did you add MineDatabase activity in AndroidManifest.xml file?
If not add it. Every component needs to be added in manifest file.